# react - how to make these Cards same height

Tags: reactjs, layout

I am doing my first react project and I am trying to make these cards the same height.  I don't want them fixed but instead based on the content.  Once that is done I am going to have a lot more content in another row underneath the cards.

Can someone point me in the right direction?  I'm guessing it has to flex but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have tried making a module.css file

```
.bigblue {
  color: DodgerBlue;
  padding: 4px;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
  /* max-width: 800px; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
}

.col {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

and changing my notes.tsx to the following:

```
export default function Notes() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/notes")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setNotes(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container className={styles.bigblue}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        {notes.map((note) => (
          <Grid className={styles.col} item key={note.id} xs={4} md={4} lg={4}>
            <NoteCard note={note} />
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
```

this is what it is looking like now... I want that 3rd box to be the same height

[image: screen]

here is my layout.tsx page
const drawerWidth = 200; //240

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
  return {
    page: {
      background: "#f1f1f1",
      width: "100%",
      padding: useTheme().spacing(3),
    },
    drawer: {
      width: drawerWidth,
    },
    drawerPaper: {
      width: drawerWidth,
    },
    root: {
      display: "flex",
    },
    active: {
      background: "#f4f4f4",
    },
    toolbar: useTheme().mixins.toolbar,
    date: {
      flexGrow: 1,
    },
    avatar: {
      marginLeft: useTheme().spacing(2),
    },
    // appbar: {
    //   width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    // },
  };
});

const Layout: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const menuItems = [
    {
      text: "My Home",
      icon: <AddCircleOutlineOutlinedIcon color="secondary" />,
      // path: "/Create",
      onClick: () => navigate("/Create"),
    },
    {
      text: "My Notes",
      icon: <SubjectOutlinedIcon color="secondary" />,
      // path: "/",
      onClick: () => navigate("/"),
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      {/* app bar */}
      <AppBar
        sx={{ width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`, ml: `${drawerWidth}px` }}
        elevation={5}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography className={classes.date}>
            Today is the {format(new Date(), "do MMMM Y")}
          </Typography>
          <Typography>Mario</Typography>
          <Avatar src="/blacksuit.png" className={classes.avatar}></Avatar>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      {/* side draw */}
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="permanent"
        anchor="left"
        classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper }}
      >
        <div>
          <Typography variant="h5">Ninja Notes</Typography>
        </div>

        {/* list / links */}
        <List>
          {menuItems.map((item) => (
            <ListItem
              key={item.text}
              onClick={item.onClick}
              // className={location.pathname == item.path ? classes.active : null}
            >
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>{item.icon}</ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={item.text}></ListItemText>
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <div className={classes.page}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar}></div>
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simple pass a `min-height` and `height: 100%;` to the cards. they will initially have the same height until the content is overflowing which will push those ones to have a larger height.

if you want the cards to be the same height always, you could add the fixed height plus adding a `overflow: auto;` to the card. This will make it so that the cards will stay withing the given height and when overflowing create a scrollable area.

Comment: thank you, so I always want all three cards to be the same height.  I would like the cards to get bigger automatically if needed, then everything below the cards to get scrollable.  (not the cards be scrollable)  does this do that?

Comment: If you want all three cards to always have the same height regardless of content you could use their container as a reference. So when 1 card is (e.g. 400px) all the others will be too. even tho (e.g. card 2 only needs a height of 200px).

From my personal experience with a row like this, I like to give the cards a min height and give them `overflow: auto;` when the content gets too much. This does require some scrollbar styling for it to look nice.

other option is to give a min-height and a height of 100%. so they will initially be the same size until the content overflows

Comment: thank you.  would you have to have an example in code.  seems way to advanced for me

Answer (score 1):

You need to use CSS `Grid` to set the height dynamically.

Check the code below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
}

.col {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore similique enim, dolor placeat magni neque iure maiores. Dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore si
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore quam deserunt, reprehenderit! Saepe nesciunt laborum, sapiente autem laboriosam quaerat officia dolore similique enim, dolor placeat magni neque iure maiores. Dicta.
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    Lorem ipsum in ut amet aute eu nulla labore do exercitation magna aliquip commodo dolore aute fugiat labore dolore ad culpa dolore pariatur qui in sed est magna cillum nisi ex deserunt sit incididunt aliquip adipisicing in officia.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried what you said and am still having trouble.  I adjusted my post to show the new outcome.  would you mind taking a look?

Comment: after looking more it depends on how big or small i make the actual chrome window.  is there a way to lock it at same heights?

Comment: I can have a look if you leave the code snippet.